# Ratio detector FM demodulator

Tags: rf, signal, ltspice, radio, frequency-modulation

The aim of the exercise is to design a ratio detector FM demodulator circuit.
[image]

UPDATE:
I changed the circuit:
[image]

This is my transient analysis in output:
[image]

I found the information about AC analysis and it would look like it:
[image]

But my result of AC analysis:
[image]

Is it good? It seems okay to me, but I cannot explain why.

Comment: There's a vague resemblance but that circuit looks wrong in a number of ways. Normally (my experience) the transformer is center-tapped on both primary and secondary and there's a capacitor that ties the center-taps together. That's missing above. The output is taken from the midpoint of the two caps after the diodes. You just ground it. There's an AGC output taken from your C1 to feed back to the earlier limiter stage. Nothing like that in your diagram. A missing resistor from mod output to secondary center-tap, etc. Why don't you explain your design? It may help a lot in helping you.

Comment: I took note of your comment and edited the schematic. What do you think? I got information from Wikipedia and a thread on the [forum](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/help-with-building-this-transformer-in-ltspice.953384/).

Comment: Your parts are as far apart as are the streets in my neighborhood. I agree that your schematic is very different to the ratio detector circuits shown in google.

Comment: @Audioguru, so what I should improve? Maybe coils are wrong? Previously, I had a capacitor connecting these coils, but in another forum they advised me to remove this capacitor.

Comment: ([Notation for transformers in LTSpice](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~tymerski/ece222/How%20to%20create%20a%20transformer%20using%20LTSpice.pdf).)

Comment: Didn't you see the Ratio Detector circuits in Google that are completely different to yours??

Comment: Can you crop your schematic? 85% of it is grey space. Do you need to expand the timebase on your traces to see the carrier and demodulation?

Comment: @Transistor: of course. I added the trace for 1ms and for 2us.

Comment: @PeterMortensen: is the transformer in current scheme ok?